# How to use check box list in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am doing my final project for my university .  I have stuck in a problem . I have a Check box list containing 3 items the first item is 1-Chinese food 2-Indian food 3-Fast food 
and down a button for the selected item .there are 3 pictures I need when I choose the Chinese food and press on the button a picture of Chinese food will appear , and when i choose the Indian food a picture of Indian food will appear and so on . Please help me how can i do that ?

Here is my vb Code

```
Partial Class About
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


        If IsPostBack Then

            Image2.Visible = True
End Class
```

The condition is if Chinese food is check the Chinese image should appear

aspx code

```
 <tr><td class="style3" colspan="2" >
     <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF66" ForeColor="Black" 
             Text="Select your food type ::"></asp:Label>
         <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" 
             Width="152px">
             <asp:ListItem>Chinese Food</asp:ListItem>

             <asp:ListItem>Indian Food</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Fast Food</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:CheckBoxList>
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Select" Width="131px" />
```

Comment: Please post your current code. We should have your code in order to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the button event handler?

Comment: How could that be done ? the button handler

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<asp:Image runat="server" ID="FoodImage" />` to your asp.net code where you want to display the image. Then in codebehind set the source of the Image control when clicking on the button by doing something like this (pseudo code):

```
protected void OnButton1_Click(object sender, EventArts e)
{
    if (IndianFood.Selected)
    {
       FoodImage.Source = "/path/to/some/image.png";
    }
}
```

**But why are you using Checkboxes for this?** I mean when you want to display only 1 image, then you should also use radiobuttons instead of checkboxes. That would ensure that the user can pick only one option instead of several. Also you could use the event `OnChecked_Changed` on the checkboxes / radiobuttons to capture clicks on the individual checkboxes / radiobuttons

Edit:
For the button handler change your button to:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="OnButton1_Click" Text="Select" Width="131px" />
```